# Red Hat 7 reset password asks for for Root password

Tags: rhel7, password-reset

I am trying to reset the root password on a rhel 7 machine

Following one of the many articles online

I first hit 'e' to get into edit mode

However after I do that is asks for a username and password?

What am I doing wrong?

I have tried putting in random passwords for root, however all it will do is reboot the machine back to the grub menu

Server is running on VMware 6.7

[image]

[image]

Comment: looks like password protection has been enabled for grub menu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords

Comment: @TomH anyway around that?

Comment: There is a tutorial here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-recovering-grub-boot-loader-password.html which suggests booting from a liveCD, and then editing the grub config from there

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot of the username prompt, it looks like password protection has been enabled for your grub menu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords

This password protection is set in the grub configuration file. Given you don't have login access to the machine, a work-around for that is to boot off a liveCD, and modify the grub config from there.

Really, any recent linux iso would do, and mount as cd in Vmware

There is a tutorial on doing that here:
https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/rhce-study-guide/how-to-reset-grub-password-in-linux.html

and here:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-recovering-grub-boot-loader-password.html

you are basically looking for a line like so, and removing it:

```
password --md5 $1$9sdflksdf/sdf44k
```